# How to force DSolve to return ODE solution in terms of BesselK instead of BesselY

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions, differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

```
sol = DSolve[{D[c[r], {r, 2}] + 1/r*D[c[r], {r, 1}] - q^2*c[r] == 0, c[a] == c0, c'[b] == 0}, c[r], r];
J[r_] = FullSimplify[D[c[r] /. sol, {r, 1}]]
```

The correct solution is returned as:

```
c0 q (BesselI[1, q r] BesselY[1, -I b q] - BesselI[1, b q] BesselY[1, -I q r])
/(I BesselI[1, b q] BesselY[0, -I a q] + BesselI[0, a q] BesselY[1, -I b q])
```

I know, however, that there is an equivalent alternative solution:

```
c0 q (BesselK[1, b q] BesselI[1, r q] - BesselK[1, r q] BesselI[1, b q])
/(BesselK[1, b q] BesselI[0, a q] + BesselK[0, a q] BesselI[1, b q])
```

My question is, how do I force Mathematica to return the solution of the ODE given in terms of BesselK functions instead of BesselY?

I can easily show that the solutions are identical to machine precision by numerical evaluation, but I really want to show that the solutions are symbolically identical.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DSolve` almost always prefers `BesselY` over `BesselK`.  To eliminate `BesselY` in favor of `BesselK` in the second block of code, tell `FullSimplify` to replace `BesselY` whenever possible:

```
cf[e_] := LeafCount[e] + 100 Count[e, _BesselY, {0, Infinity}]
FullSimplify[c0 q 
    (BesselI[1, q r] BesselY[1, -I b q] -  BesselI[1, b q] BesselY[1, -I q r])/
    (I BesselI[1, b q] BesselY[0, -I a q] + BesselI[0, a q] BesselY[1, -I b q]), 
    a q > 0 && b q > 0 && q r > 0, ComplexityFunction -> cf]

(* (c0 q (BesselI[1, q r] BesselK[1, b q] - BesselI[1, b q] BesselK[1, q r]))/
   (BesselI[1, b q] BesselK[0, a q] + BesselI[0, a q] BesselK[1, b q]) *)
```

Answer (score 4):

FunctionExpand also works.

```
expr = c0 q (BesselI[1, q r] BesselY[1, -I b q] - 
     BesselI[1, b q] BesselY[1, -I q r])/(I BesselI[1, b q] BesselY[0, -I a q] + BesselI[0, a q] BesselY[1, -I b q])

FullSimplify[FunctionExpand[expr], a q > 0 && b q > 0 && q r > 0]

(*(c0 q (BesselK[1, b q] BesselI[1, q r] - 
   BesselI[1, b q] BesselK[1, q r]))/(
BesselK[0, a q] BesselI[1, b q] + BesselI[0, a q] BesselK[1, b q])*)
```